# Mysql: Getting error code 1452 - Cannot update child row

Tags: mysql, database

As the title says.  I checked a few of the stackoverflow responses and tried implementing their solutions but still get the error 1452.

I grabbed [this database (Countries/states/cities)](https://github.com/hiiamrohit/Countries-States-Cities-database)

and applied it to my database.

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Countries;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Countries (
      id int(11) NOT NULL,# AUTO_INCREMENT,
      sortname varchar(3) NOT NULL,
      name varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      phonecode int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );

    DROP Table if EXISTS States;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS States (
      id int(11) NOT NULL,
      name varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      countryId int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id),
      FOREIGN KEY (countryId) REFERENCES Countries(id)
    );

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cities;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Cities (
      id int(11) NOT NULL,
      name varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      stateId int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id),
      FOREIGN KEY (stateId) references States (id)
    );
```

My inserts:

```
    INSERT INTO  Countries (`id`, `sortname`, `name`, `phonecode`) VALUES 
    (1, 'AF', 'Afghanistan', 93),
    (2, 'AL', 'Albania', 355),
    (3, 'DZ', 'Algeria', 213),
    (4, 'AS', 'American Samoa', 1684),
    (5, 'AD', 'Andorra', 376),
    ...

    #TRUNCATE TABLE States;
    INSERT INTO States(`id`, `name`, `countryId`) VALUES
    (1, 'Andaman and Nicobar Islands', 101),
    (2, 'Andhra Pradesh', 101),
    (3, 'Arunachal Pradesh', 101),
    (4, 'Assam', 101),
    (5, 'Bihar', 101),
    ...

    #TRUNCATE TABLE Cities;
    INSERT INTO Cities (`id`, `name`, `stateId`) VALUES
    (1, 'Bombuflat', 1),
    (2, 'Garacharma', 1),
    (3, 'Port Blair', 1),
    (4, 'Rangat', 1),
    (5, 'Addanki', 2),
    ...
    );
```

My thoughts on the error are that originally, the create tables were auto-incremented, but the guy that created/copied the db still inserts the id, which I believe isn't necessary.  So after trying a few things I removed the auto-increment. No resolve on that unfortunately.  The other thing I'm thinking is that perhaps the foreign keys(ids) are not matching the parent table? But when I do a simple select statement like

```
Select * from States where id = 673; # 'Quebec'
```

I get the right response.  What is the right way to solve this kind of problem?

Edit: Of course I got it working without foreign key (by copying his repository directly) but I think thats not the right way. I think foreign keys are necessary for this.

Edit2: Added the foreign keys to the original sql script:

```
    SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
    SET time_zone = "+00:00";

    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
    /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `states` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES Countries(`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4121 ;

    /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

That made it work, I have no idea why :(

Comment: Are you running all of that in the order you posted it? And you get the error on your last statement (`INSERT INTO Cities` statement)?

Comment: Yes.  However I added an edit and managed to get it working(without foreign keys).  Secondly I JUST added the foreign keys to the guys code and it works.  I don't understand why but I'll post the table structure in a second..